# Ruby/Rails eqv PHP get_meta_tags

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, equivalent

Is there an equivalent ruby/RoR method for PHP `get_meta_tags.`

I am looking to read the meta tag information of a given url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [Hpricot](http://github.com/why/hpricot/tree/master) and do something like:

```
doc = Hpricot(URI.parse("http://example.com/").read)
(doc/'/html/head/meta')
  #=> Elements[...]
```

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about using a screen scrape utility, but I was hoping there was a built in Ruby method with maybe HTTP::Net or something. I will just use Nokogiri since it is already installed on my dev machines. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot.

It work for me. I am trying to get description form meta tag.
my code is like

```
def self.extract_description_from_url(url)
  description = ""
  doc = Hpricot(URI.parse(url).read)
  (doc/'/html/head/meta').each do |meta|
    val=  meta.get_attribute('name')
    if val == "description" 
      description = meta.get_attribute('content')
    end
  end
  return description
end
```

Comment: could also write: `meta_desc = (doc/'/html/head/meta').find {|meta| meta.get_attribute('name') == "description"}; description = meta_desc.nil? : "" ? meta_desc.get_attribute('content')`